# ability to add a 3D Avatar that can be customised on a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d, avatar-generation

I am designing an app where we would like to have a capability for users to edit their avatars style. like hair colour and body colour.
The app needs to be built on flutter, I checked out various libraries like Rive (Flare) but they do not seem to be working with 3D assets.

I came across this app called VOS which is doing something similar
[image]

Any leads will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You can import basic 3D model using this package [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_3d_obj] and change it color property. or You can Do this Using THREE.js if you know how to integrate javascipt with flutter

Comment: I am the UX/UI designer of the project with a little bit of Flutter experience, the flutter dev for the team who will be joining us, has recently learned flutter. would you say this kind of functionality is hard to achieve for a single dev to complete in a 2-3 weeks?

Comment: Yes, it is hard, for single developer and with beginner level, but you have plenty of time, I mean in 2-3 week even newbie can do this.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_3d_obj  I realized that above link is not working , sorry for that please go to package using this link .

Comment: HI Yash,
Thank you for the link, it works.
I will read through the documentation and see whats possible.

Comment: hi @SanketS, i'm also facing the same issue, did you managed to code that out?

Comment: @scottlee. - Nah, that library does not work well and someone suggested unity but its prices were a bit too much for a starting project. I have moved onto rive.app, adding 2D animations and character select options (not happy about it)
If you find a better alternative. please do comment back

Comment: ok i'll let you know if i find a better alternative

Comment: I moved to Rive, making it look 3D ish and making it work, but now they have introduced raster support so you can export you image png and put it on bones and use them